# Installing WLAN driver to laptop w/ no internet

Tags: drivers, wireless, broadcom

I am trying to install a WLAN driver in order to get internet access on my laptop. I can only add files to this laptop via a USB stick, there is no other way to connect to the internet using this laptop until I have a WLAN connection. As such, I cannot use repositories to install anything.

WLAN is: Dell Wireless 1390 WLAN Mini-Card BCM4311 [14e4:4311]
Laptop is: Inspiron 1520 (32 bit)
Ubuntu Version is: 16.04 LTS

Please can someone talk me through how to install the driver via USB. I have tried Broadcom's advice (http://www.broadcom.com/docs/linux_sta/README_6.30.223.271.txt) but it assumes you already have an internet connection.

Comment: You do not need `bcmwl`, you need firmware.

Answer (score -1):

Try **ip** command.

```
$ ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

if wlan0 appear, you can continue.

```
$ ip link set wlan0 up
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted
$ sudo ip link set wlan0 up
[sudo] password for user: 
$ whatis ip
ip (8)               - show / manipulate routing, devices, policy routing and tunnels
ip (7)               - Linux IPv4 protocol implementation
$ ifconfig wlan0
bash: ifconfig: command not found
$ sudo ifconfig wlan0
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

> ***XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX*** : your hardware mac

Comment: How is it related to the question?